# Removing -th characters in every row in a column but only when they come after a number

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a list of addresses, such as 16388 28TH AVENUE. The geocoder for some reason prefers to deal with addresses without the -th. How do I delete them, keeping in mind that there could be streets that contain th combination, therefore only when -th comes after a number?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips on those articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part `(?<=\d)` checks that there is a number before, last part `(?=\s)` checks that there is a space after.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(ST|ND|RD|TH)(?=\s)", "","16388 28TH AVENUE")
'16388 28 AVENUE'
```

Added `(ST|ND|RD|TH)` for the rest of the possible numbers

Comment: The problem is most likely not unique to `th`, so probably want to have `(?:ST|ND|RD|TH)`